# I am getting an “eth0: no such device” when running android-x86-4.0 on a VirtualBox VM in bridged mode

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, android-x86

Recently I installed `android-x86-4.0-r1.1-asus_laptop.iso` on  VirtualBox virtual machine.

After installation I set `network` type as `bridge adapter, eth0` and started the virtual machine then opened terminal emulator and executed `netcfg` command to determine the IP. But `eth0` is not listed there in results.

How I can solve this problem? Did I do some thing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ifconfig` now. Just found out that `ifconfig eth0` does not work in my case, because the bridge adapter eth0 of VirtualBox does not show up as eth0 within the android x86. Just use the bare `ifconfig` command. The IP address found in the output within the wlan section worked in my case in order to do `adb connect IP:5555`, where IP is the IP address.